# Start two activities from Android application

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an application `A` that wants to start an `Activity` in another application, `B`, which I don't own and cannot edit.

If `B` is already running and visible in recent apps, there's no problem in executing the wanted `Activity` of `B` using an `Intent`.

If `B` isn't running, I use the following code to execute its main `Activity` first, and then the one I want to execute:

```
String bPackage = "com.example.applicationb";
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(this);
Intent main = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(bPackage);
Intent wanted = new Intent();
wanted.setPackage(bPackage);
wanted.setComponent(new ComponentName(bPackage,bPackage+".WantedActivity"));
main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
wanted.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
wanted.setExtras(mPreviouslyCreatedBundle);
startActivity(main);
startActivity(wanted);
```

The wanted `Activity` executes, but after some seconds I get an error and it stops working. Am I setting the `Intent`s in a wrong way?

Comment: Refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684263/android-start-multiple-activities

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel I just tried the answer by RaginMari, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure u have setted `exported="true"` for activity you are trying to redirect to another package

Basically my idea is  when your second paackage app leave  u need :

```
android.os.process.killprocess(android.os.process.mypid())
```

and when you launch use flag as start new task :

```
setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: According to manifest, both `main` and `wanted` activities have `exported="true"`

Comment: startActivity(main);
startActivity(wanted); will lead to only one activity to be fornt one at time and whast the erorr can u post here?

Comment: After some tests I found out that my procedure, same proposed by you, was correct. There's a bug in `B` application and I'm going to report the issue on their GitHub.